# SQL/PHP: Show top 3 most sold products from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, count

I have a database containing the following tables:

```
 - product (product_id / name / price / image_id / description)
 - order ( order_id / date / status / email )
 - order_count ( order_id / product_id / number )
 - image (image_id / image_link )
```

I'd like to show the 3 most sold products on my homepage, but can't wrap my head around doing this.

I tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT" * 
FROM 'product' INNER JOIN 'afbeelding' 
WHERE 'product'.'image_id' = 'afbeelding'.'image_id'
GROUP BY 'product_id'
ORDER BY 'product_id' DESC
LIMIT 3;";
```

I can't seem to find out where and how to place a `'count'` in this query..
Thanks

Comment: Put count(*) in the select list.

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions, but most return error 500  or no return at all when reloading the page showing the php/sql..

Comment: 'product' is a string \`product\` is a table identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(order_count.number) AS total, image.image_link AS image_link 
FROM product JOIN order_count 
ON product.product_id = order_count.product_id 
JOIN image ON product.image_id = image.image_id
GROUP BY order_count.product_id 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 3";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did work in the end! If you're ever in Holland, I'll grab you a beer! ;-)

Comment: One more thing though.. I also need to show the image I linked to a product.. just can't get it to show any images.. any ideas as to where I need to place this piece of code ( I think this is the code I need to show images) `product`.`image_id` = `afbeelding`.`image_id`

Comment: I edited the code to include joining the image database table, try if it works for you.

Comment: That's two beers for you! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query :

```
$sql = "SELECT p.*,af.*, IFNULL(SUM(oc.number), 0) as total_quantity 
FROM (`product` as p) 
INNER JOIN `afbeelding` as af ON `af`.`image_id` = `p`.`image_id` 
INNER JOIN `order_count` as oc ON `oc`.`product_id` = `p`.`product_id` 
GROUP BY `p`.`product_id` ORDER BY `total_quantity` DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
SELECT * FOM products p INNER JOIN order_count oc 
ON p.product_id=oc.product_id 
GROUP BY 'product_id'
ORDER BY 'product_id' DESC
LIMIT 3;";
```

Answer (score 0):

select p.name as 'Product Name', x.total as 'Total' 
from product p 
inner join (select product_id as product_id, sum(number) as total from order_count group by product_id) x 
on x.product_id = p.product_id 
order by x.total DESC limit 3;