# How to list the best-selling products from sql

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a list of top 5 sold products.
in `orders_form` table, each row have `count`.
the php should count row numbers and quantity from `count` to list products from 1 to 5 level

This is my database 'orders_form':

```
|  id  | product_id |    count   | single_price |
|  1   |      7     |      2     |      100     |
|  2   |      3     |      1     |      100     |
|  3   |      9     |      3     |      100     |
|  4   |      3     |      1     |      100     |
```

it's what i try'd :

```
$total = 'SELECT * FROM orders_form group by product_id ORDER BY single_price DESC';
$statement = $conn->query($total);
foreach($statement as $row) {
    echo $row['product_id'] . ' - ' . $row['single_price'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

but it doesn't work the way I want it to... 
this is the second try [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654322/sql-php-show-top-3-most-sold-products-from-database):

```
$total = "SELECT SUM(count.number) AS total
FROM orders_form JOIN count
ON orders_form.product_id = count.product_id 
GROUP BY count.product_id 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 3";
print_r($statement);
```

and it's white screen

Comment: Search for  "PHP white screen".

Comment: In the second try, the query is not run?

Comment: @PaulT. no, and there is no error

Comment: ...so then the white screen is from which example? There's really not enough info to know if there could be something before/after those points contributing to the issue.

Comment: What you can try, is at the top of the script (temporarily) add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`, and then reload.

Comment: @PaulT. just forget about white screen. what i've try'd isn't working. just let me know if you can help me to list best-selling products

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217249/discussion-between-paul-t-and-mrdev).

Answer (score 0):

after all discussion in the chat, here is the working code:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user","pass","pw");
if ($conn->connect_errno) { 
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
} else {
    echo 'Connection success <br>' ;
}

$total = "SELECT product_id, SUM(`count`)*single_price AS total FROM `orders_form` GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5";
$statement = $conn->query($total);
if (!$statement = $conn->query($total)) {
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $conn->error;
} else {
    foreach($statement as $row){
        echo $row['product_id'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```